# On a laptop which consumes more power - cordless mouse or wired mouse?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, mouse, battery-life, wireless-mouse

Which consumes least power from the laptop battery out of the following - a corded USB mouse or a cordless mouse with USB transceiver or bluetooth wireless mouse?

I have a laptop running Windows 7 64-bit and am looking to use a solution that'll use the least amount of energy from my laptop's battery. yes, I know the built-in touchpad would use the least energy but I'd like to use an external device - more comfort.

Either via practical experience or via tests carried out, could someone please help to narrow down the type of mouse that'd serve my purpose? Not looking for a fancy mouse - 2 button + wheel is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few years back Toms Hardware did a review of items that related to the power consumption of notebooks.  Their testing at the time revealed that a bluetooth mouse is very slightly better.  The complete coverage can be read [here](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/squeezing-more-life-out-of-your-notebook,review-583-13.html).

[image: From Tom's Hardware]

Answer (score 0):

I would assess that wire mouse is the more likely to be the best choice. 
I guess it depends on the manufacturer, but the BlueTooth and/or transceiver generally requires a lot of power to communicate and I think more than the full powering of a wire mouse.

Unfortunately I have no source to refer to.